# PowerShell command tracing

Tags: powershell

I have worked and created many script in UNIX but I am new to PowerShell and looking for some help as the world knows stackoverflow is best for this.

Now we know

**sh -x script_name.sh**

runs a shell script in interactive mode and display commands line by line as they are executed.

CAN THIS BE DONE IN POWERSHELL ?

I want PowerShell script to executed in Interactive mode

**.\Script_name.ps1** just simply executes it. 
Please help.

Comment: This is not "interactive mode" at all. This is **tracing**. Please change your question title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Set-PSDebug` cmdlet to set [debug features](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849697.aspx) on or off.  For example, `set-psdebug -trace 0` will disable tracing and `set-psdebug -trace 2` will trace in very verbose a mode.

Comment: its all good but is it possible that this happens only when I execute script

Comment: @user2698972 Sure, just put set-psdebug commands as first and last statements in your script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell debugging cmdlets to achieve this. You need to add a break-points.

Available cmdlets are:

```
 - New-PsBreakpoint
 - Get-PsBreakpoint
 - Enable-PsBreakpoint
 - Disable-PsBreakpoint
 - Remove-PsBreakpoint
 - Step-Into
 - Step-Out
```

Setting a break-point is as simple as:-

```
New-PSBreakpoint -script .\Script_name.ps1 -line 4
```

Refer [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730925.aspx) document for further details